# How to execute alphanumaric string in java

Tags: java, exception

When I give CS1001  as an input the output has to show a valid message. Apart from that every input must be invalid. I don't understand what logic I have to apply for it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeInfo {
    private static final String CSXXX = "";

    public void empCheck(String empId) throws InvalidEmployeeException {
        if (!CSXXX.equals(empId))
            throw new InvalidEmployeeException("Employee ID inValid");
        else
            System.out.println("Employee ID is Valid");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Main Starts....");
        EmployeeInfo ei = new EmployeeInfo();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Employee ID");
        String w = sc.nextLine();
        try {
            ei.empCheck(w);
        } catch (InvalidEmployeeException iee) {
            System.out.println(iee);
        }
        System.out.println("Main End...");
    }
}
```

InvalidEmployeeException.java

```
public class InvalidEmployeeException extends Exception {
    public InvalidEmployeeException(String s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        super(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: At `if (!CSXXX.equals(empId))` you are testing if `empId` is different than value of `CSXXX` which is set to hold empty string `""`, so that condition will be true for every non-empty string. You probably want to set `CSXXX` to `"CS1001"`.

Comment: If i set string to "CS1001", the output is valid. What if i give "CS2012" ? the output is invalid. But my question is whenever the input is starts with CS then the output statement must be true.

Comment: "*But my question is whenever the input is starts with CS then the output statement must be true*" that is the first time you mention it... Anyway for that cases String has `startsWith` method. Try to apply it in your code.

Comment: i tried  startsWith method. Still showing me the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeInfo {

    String Str = "CS";

    public void empCheck(String empId) throws InvalidEmployeeException {

        if (!empId.startsWith(Str)) 

            // if (!CSXXX.equals(empId))
            throw new InvalidEmployeeException("Employee ID is inValid");
        else
            System.out.println("Employee ID is Valid");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Main Starts....");
        EmployeeInfo ei = new EmployeeInfo();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Employee ID");
        String w = sc.nextLine();

        try {
            ei.empCheck(w);
        } catch (InvalidEmployeeException iee) {
            System.out.println(iee);
        }
        System.out.println("Main End...");
    }

}
```